# stuck on building extranet

Tags: extranet

I need some help. They asked me to build an extranet for our customers. The only thing it must do is sharing documents. I want to do this with sharepoint foundation 2010.

But here is the thing. i am stuck in setting up the basics.

this is what i was thinking:

First i need a portal page which allows customers to login. There will be only 1 site collection, because multiple customers will share documents (they are working on the same projects).
So customers have access to multiple subsites. i know this is going to be a security risk, but i don't see how i must do it otherwise.

What will be the quickest way to accomplish this ?

are there any examples out there for this kind of extranet ?

thx !

Marco Nedermeijer

Answer (score 1):

I think one of the first things you should work out is what you will use for authentication and authorization. You stated that you want a login page (which implies using forms-based authentication) but what will you use as your user store?

Do your customers have accounts in an active directory,or would you prefer to use a separate database for managing users (ie SqlMembership)?

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand what kind of security risks you can face?

you can set specifics permissions to any users/sites/lists/items

so it's up to you to secure your intranet

will you use the FBA ?